# Is there a HeartBleed Honeypot so that I can pentest it?

Tags: heartbleed

I am looking to improve my skills, to do so I need a site with an old OpenSSL version, so that I can do a pentest on my own.

Comment: It would take you about 10 minutes to set one up yourself

Answer (score 5):

It should be easy to create one of your own, which is usually preferable. Fire up apache, install an old libssl (prior to 1.0.1f) and give your install a self-signed cert. Then, generate some traffic with curl.

You should be able to fire up your exploit and start reading memory.

It's probably best to do this in a VM, since you don't want anyone else exploiting your test bed.

Answer (score 2):

Cloudflare operates some servers over at [cloudflarechallenge.com](http://cloudflarechallenge.com) that are vulnerable to heartbleed.

You can verify it with nmap:

```
sudo nmap --script ssl-heartbleed cloudflarechallenge.com -d

443/tcp open  https   syn-ack
| ssl-heartbleed:
|   VULNERABLE:
|   The Heartbleed Bug is a serious vulnerability in the popular OpenSSL cryptographic software library. It allows for stealing information intended to be protected by SSL/TLS encryption.
|     State: VULNERABLE
|     Risk factor: High
```